# How to remove the 'Design' tab from an xml document within Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

The standard eclipse xml editor has a 'design' tab at the bottom. The problem with those bottom tabs is that when using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> / <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to scroll through the open editors it will always get stuck on xml files.

Any of you have an idea to remove the design tab or have a workaround so it won't stop on that tab?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the xml file and select 'Open With' and select 'Text Editor'.

You may also go to Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations and define a particular editor that you want to use by default for files ending with .xml

Comment: Fine solution, although I rather have an editor with color syntax and content assist.

Comment: While I was looking for something else, your solution provided me with a clue where to look. I kept having the Design tab instead of the Graphical Layout tab whenever I opened xml files, and apparently the defaults got reset somehow. My sanity is restored.

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open the tab in list.

Comment: I knew this shortcut already. It's just that i am used to working with the pageup/down shortkey :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't they fix this with Galileo (3.5)? I know this always bugged me too but went away in some version. Anyway, you can customize the shortcuts in Preferences - General - Keys. The relevant entries are *Next/Previous Sub-Tab*. Galileo uses <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PgDown</kbd> / <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

Comment: I use 3.4, so i don't know if this has been fixed. I couldn't find the mentioned key entries, maybe they are added in 3.5?

Comment: That's possible and you might be out of luck. Why not upgrade to 3.5? 3.6 is out already, maybe even upgrade to that.

Answer (score 0):

To open Source tab with XML editor in Eclipse Neon 2 you must go to Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Content Assist

There in the second list of proposal categories, move "XML Tag Proposals" to first position.